# Using the most general typeclass function types

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a simple genetic algorithm in Haskell. I figured the first step should be to make a typeclass for individuals that are 'genetic', like so:

```hs
class Genetic a where
    fitness :: (Ord b) => a -> b
```

This seems reasonable to me - I don't necessarily want to restrict fitness functions to a type like `Float` or `Double`, and conceptually all a fitness function should do is provide an ordering of the individuals.

However, when I implement this typeclass for a `String` wrapper:

```hs
data DNA = DNA String
instance Genetic DNA where
    fitness (DNA s) = length s
```

I see the following error in GHC:

```
Could not deduce (b ~ Int)
from the context (Ord b)
  bound by the type signature for fitness :: Ord b => DNA -> b
```

Is this not how I should define typeclass functions? Do I have to restrict the function to a specific concrete type, or provide another type variable to the typeclass constructor?

Comment: This is a common problem.  Your signature means that the *caller* gets to choose the orderable type, so `fitness` must be able to fabricate a value of any orderable type and return it.  Note, `Void` (the type with no values) is orderable, so this is impossible.  You probably want to parameterize `Genetic` on the order space: `class (Ord b) => Genetic b a  where fitness :: a -> b`

Comment: @luqui Thanks, I think I get it. Trying that out, it seems vanilla Haskell doesn't like multi-type-parameter typeclasses. Who'd have thought.

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster yes but the `MultiParamTypeclasses` extension is pretty common to use

Comment: @jozefg Fair enough, I was just surprised that it was an extension.

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster Haskell 98 (or 2010) is a pretty darn conservative language, most of the crazy stuff you see happening today such as lens or cloud haskell are pretty heavily dependent on language extensions that tie them to GHC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Luqui explained what the problem is: `fitness` would need to be able to provide *any* `Ord` instance the caller might request, when what you really want is *some specific one that suits the type best*.

This is IMO a very nice application for associated type synonyms:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

class (Ord (Fitness a)) => Genetic a where
  type Fitness a :: *
  fitness :: a -> Fitness a

data DNA = DNA String
instance Genetic DNA where
  type Fitness DNA = Int
  fitness (DNA s) = length s
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's cool. I think I might just go this way. Thanks!

Comment: Except, I get an error: `Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Ord (Fitness a)`. It does say `(Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this)` - sounds like another pragma is required?

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster, yeah, be prepared to put in any extension the compiler recommends at this point.  Typeclass code is sometimes like that...

Comment: Though if the compiler recommends `IncoherentInstances`, it might be time to reconsider.